# Conversion of a Dataframe to a Tensor

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, tensorflow, bert-language-model

I have a dataframe lets say a shape [10,4] in which column 3 and 4 of shape[1,246]. How can I convert it or let say reshape it in such a way that it can be converted into a proper tensor.

Problem in brief:-
I am actually having a dataset with shape [10,2]  which i am using for bert to train. After tokenising one of its column with bert tokenizer i get input_ids of shape [1,23] which is saved as a new column in the dataframe changing the shape as [10,3] where 3 column is of shape[1,23]. Now I want to feed this to my bert model to train for which i neeed to convert it into a tensor. Help me out with the best approach for this.

The below image attached is can help you out to understand what kind of
problem I am facing.

This whole dataframe is of shape[5000,4] where as the element column[input_ids] array has shape [1,56] where 56 is the maximum tokeized words.
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your current code, ideally with sample inputs for your dataframes.

Comment: @dennlinger modified this question, hope it work now

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Numpy array, like this:

```
a = [1, 2]
np.asarray(a)
array([1, 2])
```

Comment: no lets consider the first row of this dataframe to be [1,[2,3,4]5,6] and i want to convert it into a tensor

Comment: please refer the attached image.

Comment: I like images, but in this case actual data may be better. Maybe you have a list of lists and you need to flatten it and convert that to an array? Not sure. You can try this:

flat_list = [item for sublist in mylist for item in sublist]

Or, see the link below. Again, this is just a guess.

https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-flatten-a-list-of-lists-in-python